# IntelliJ add * on each comment line after pressing enter

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, to create a comment-block I can do <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, but it doesn't fill-down an `*` on all lines. Additionally, pressing enter goes to a new-line without copying down the `*`. Is there a way to auto-fill things, such that it looks more like this?

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2022 by Bob Jones
 *
 * The MIT license.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
```

Comment: The `*` on every line is not required for a multiline comment and it's used very rarely (in my personal experience), so I would be kind of surprised if there is a built-in way of doing that. You could probably find or write a plugin for it though.

Comment: @Jesse -- of course, but it adds a nice consistent 'left-border', and I've seen it used quite frequently in various codebases.

Comment: In JavaScript there is an intention "Replace with JSDoc comment" in Alt+Enter menu. It might help.

Comment: related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128999/Option-to-auto-insert-asteriks-in-multiline-comments-after-first-line

Comment: @Oksana that seems like it might be good enough. Want to post an answer with how to do that, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit Alt+Enter on the comment and select "Replace with JSDoc comment" intention from the list of actions.
[image]